# How to check data when loop entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreach

I use entity framework and i have a table. The data is

```
Code    Check   Num
C1      true    10
C1      false   20
C2      true    15
C1      false   15
C1      true    15
C1      true    20
C2      false   10
```

Ok, and I'll filter data by code = "C1" and found a row with Check = "true" and Num = "15". I use code as follows:

```
var list = db.PRODUCTes.Where(e=>e.Code == C1);
var flag=0;
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (list.Select(e => e.Check).SingleOrDefault() == true && list.Select(e => e.Num).SingleOrDefault() == 15)
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
    else
        flag = 2;
}
return flag;
```

When I run it, the value of flag is 2. I think it does not work.

Comment: I doubt your code even throws some exception at `.SingleOrDefault()`. Your `list.Select(e => e.Check)` surely has more than 1 item, so `SingleOrDefault` would throw exception. Strangely that you don't have that exception?

Comment: next time please be ***honest*** when describing what you did, it's ridiculous to hear this ***When run it, the value of flag is 2*** with what you posted.

Comment: Why did you use the foreach loop? I'm asking because I didn't see the "item" anywhere...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use Enumerable Any? [Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var flag = db.PRODUCTes.Any(e => e.Code == C1 && e.Check && e.Num == 15) ? 1 : 2;
```

The ? is the conditional operator in C#. Read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you continue to iterate after detecting the wanted value resulting in resetting the value of flag to 2. You should break after finding the value:

```
if (list.Select(e => e.Check).SingleOrDefault() == true && list.Select(e => e.Num).SingleOrDefault() == 15)
{
    flag = 1;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to check your list if any of the items has check 'true' and num = '15'. You can do that with the following code:

```
var list = db.PRODUCTes.Where(e=>e.Code == C1);
if(list.Any(e => e.Check == true && e.Num == "15"))
   return 1;
return 2;
```

The reason why it failed for you earlier is because that you overwrite your flag variable, because of the foreach loop.